# Ошибка компиляции модуля DirectMySQL

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, компиляция, delphi-10-berlin

Возникла проблема при компиляции проекта написанного на Delphi7. Установлен Rad Studio 10.3.

Проект содержит сторонний модуль MySQLDirect для доступа к базе MySQL.

Теперь при попытке компиляции выдаёт ошибку:

> ошибка [dcc32 Error] uMysqlVio.pas(970): E2089 Invalid typecast

На строке:

```
 sock_addr.sin_addr:=in_addr(ip_addr);
```

Прошу помочь, если кто сталкивался или знает решение. Переписывать проект под другие процедуры доступа займёт не менее месяца, но возможно.

Выборку связанного кода прилагаю:

```
const

  AF_UNIX         = 1;
  AF_INET         = 2;
  SOCK_STREAM     = 1;
  SOCKET_ERROR    = -1;
  INADDR_NONE     = $FFFFFFFF;

type

  SunB = packed record
    s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4: char;
  end;

  SunW = packed record
    s_w1, s_w2: word;
  end;

  in_addr = record
    case longint of  //longint
      0: (S_un_b: SunB);
      1: (S_un_w: SunW);
      2: (S_addr: longint); //longint
  end;

  TSockAddr = record
    case Integer of
      0: (sa_family: word;
          sa_data: packed array[0..13] of Byte);
      1: (sin_family: word;
          sin_port: word;
          sin_addr: in_addr;
          sin_zero: packed array[0..7] of Byte);
  end;  

function inet_addr(cp: PChar): longint; stdcall; external 'wsock32.dll' name 'inet_addr';


function TMysqlVio.vio_open( _type:TEnumVioType; host:string='localhost'; unix_socket:string={$IFDEF _WIN_}MYSQL_NAMEDPIPE{$ELSE}MYSQL_UNIX_ADDR{$ENDIF}; port:longint=0; connect_timeout:cardinal=0; trysock:boolean=true): longint;
var
  sock:longint;
  {$IFDEF _WIN_}
  hPipe:longint;
  szPipeName:string[255];
  i:integer;
  dwMode:longword;
  {$ELSE}
  haserr:boolean;
  Unixaddr:TUnixSockAddr;
  {$ENDIF}
  sock_addr:TSockAddr;
  ip_addr:cardinal;
  hp:phostent;
  lhost:string; //store temp values
  lunix_socket:string; //store temp values
begin
....
....
          ip_addr := {$IFOPT R+}cardinal{$ENDIF}(inet_addr(pchar(host))); // thanks Jiri Barton

          if (ip_addr <> INADDR_NONE) then
          begin
          sock_addr.sin_addr:=in_addr(ip_addr); //ошибка [dcc32 Error] uMysqlVio.pas(970): E2089 Invalid typecast
          end
          else
          begin
            hp:=gethostbyname(pchar(host));
            if (hp=nil) then
            begin
                flast_errno:=CR_UNKNOWN_HOST;
              {$IFDEF _WIN_}
              flast_error:=format(client_errors[(flast_errno)-CR_MIN_ERROR],[host, WSAGetLastError]);
              {$ELSE}
              flast_error:=format(client_errors[(flast_errno)-CR_MIN_ERROR],[host, errno]);
              {$ENDIF}
                result:=-7; //we can't connect
              closesocket(sock);
                exit;
            end;
            ip_addr:=byte(hp.h_addr^[0])+(byte(hp.h_addr^[1])shl 8)+(byte(hp.h_addr^[2])shl 16)+(byte(hp.h_addr^[3])shl 24);
            sock_addr.sin_addr:=in_addr(ip_addr); //ошибка [dcc32 Error] uMysqlVio.pas(970): E2089 Invalid typecast
            hp.h_length:=10;
          end;

....
....
end;
```

Comment: Так если *"Invalid typecast"*, то какой тип нужно присваивать и какой вы присваиваете вместо этого? P.S. Версия 10.3 еще не вышла.

Comment: По идее там должен присваиваться IP адрес сервера MySQL, в каком виде               `in_addr = record
 case longint of  //longint
      0: (S_un_b: SunB);
      1: (S_un_w: SunW);
      2: (S_addr: longint); //longint`

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать данный юнит с Delphi Xe - вам придется полностью его перелопатить, после Delphi 7 изменились все стандартные типы данных... p.s. в интернете мне удавалось наткнутся на готовые решения, но было это очень давно...